# xslt to flatten xml nodes child nodes and grandchild nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am starting to learn xslt to manipulate xml and trying to flatten xml that has many different child nodes and grandchild nodes. Is there any simple xslt to convert the input xml to produce output.xml.

input.xml:

```
<Addresses>
  <Address__c>
    <Id>a0H20000002uhsyEAA</Id>
    <R00N20000001XA10EAG>
        <Customer_Installation_Address__c>
            <Id>a0L2000000DDpOCEA1</Id>
        </Customer_Installation_Address__c>
        <Customer_Installation_Address__c>
            <Id>a0L2000000DDpOCEB2</Id>
        </Customer_Installation_Address__c>
    </R00N20000001XA10EAG>
    <Customers__r>
        <Account>
            <Id>001M000000FOEiHIAX</Id>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <Id>001M000000FOAAbIAP</Id>
        </Account>
    </Customers__r>
    <Cases__r>
        <Case>
            <Id>500D000000G7drpIAB</Id>
        </Case>
    </Cases__r>
   </Address__c>
   <Address__c>
    <Id>a0H20000003JjyzEAC</Id>
    <Cases__r>
        <Case>
            <Id>500D000000G7drpIAB</Id>
        </Case>
    </Cases__r>
   </Address__c>
   <Address__c>
    <Id>a0HD0000007wQ0EMAU</Id>
    <Customers__r>
        <Account>
            <Id>001M000000FOEiHIAX</Id>
        </Account>
        <Account>
            <Id>001M000000FOAAbIAP</Id>
        </Account>
    </Customers__r>
   </Address__c>
</Addresses>
```

and want to product the following xml output.

output.xml

```
<Addresses>
  <Address__c>
    <AddrId>a0H20000002uhsyEAA</AddrId>
    <CIAddressId>a0L2000000DDpOCEA1</CIAddressId>
    <CIAddressId>a0L2000000DDpOCEB2</CIAddressId>
    <AccountId>001M000000FOEiHIAX</AccountId>
    <AccountId>001M000000FOAAbIAP</AccountId>
    <CaseId>500D000000G7drpIAB</CaseId>
  </Address__c>
  <Address__c>
    <AddrId>a0H20000003JjyzEAC</AddrId>
    <CaseId>500D000000G7drpIAB</CaseId>
  </Address__c>
  <Address__c>
    <AddrId>a0HD0000007wQ0EMAU</AddrId>
    <AccountId>001M000000FOEiHIAX</AccountId>
    <AccountId>001M000000FOAAbIAP</AccountId>
   </Address__c>
</Addresses>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (there are more succinct ways to express it):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Addresses>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Addresses/Address__c" />
    </Addresses>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Address__c">
    <Address__c>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::Id" />
    </Address__c>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Id">
    <Id><xsl:value-of select="." /></Id>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would give you

```
<Addresses>
<Address__c>
    <Id>a0H20000002uhsyEAA</Id>
    <Id>a0L2000000DDpOCEA1</Id>
    <Id>a0L2000000DDpOCEB2</Id>
    <!-- ... -->
```

Now you can add extra templates to change the name of the `Id` element depending on its parent:

```
<xsl:template match="Address__c/Id">
  <AddrId><xsl:value-of select="." /></AddrId>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Customer_Installation_Address__c/Id">
  <CIAddressId><xsl:value-of select="." /></CIAddressId>
</xsl:template>
```

etc.